# guard statement variable do not give me value

Tags: swift

```
var country = ""
 if placemark.country != nil{
      country = placemark.country!
  }
 self.awareLocationDetaile.text = country
```

Try to convert this code guard statement

```
guard let country = placemark.country else{                        
     return    
 }
self.awareLocationDetaile.text = country
```

but unfortunate country have no value if i use **guard** statement where **if** give me value . what am i missing ?

UPDATE :

```
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { ( clPlacemark :[CLPlacemark]?,error : NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
               print(error)
            }else{
                if let placemark = clPlacemark?[0]{
                 // print(placemark)
                    //MARK:- we are a good programmer
//                    var country = ""
//                    if placemark.country != nil{
//                        country = placemark.country!
//                    }
//                  self.awareLocationDetaile.text = country


                    guard let country = placemark.country else{

                        return

                    }


                    self.awareLocationDetaile.text = country
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: @pedrouan please check my Update section

Comment: Try an answer below.

Comment: @pedrouan this error throwing :- downcast from string? to string only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'? . what should i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guard statement works exactly as it is supposed to work. You are not missing anything. It does what it is supposed to do, not what you want. Your first code sample can be written a lot easier as

```
self.awareLocationDetaile.text = placemark.country ?? ""
```

It seems you copied a comment that the queen wrote after she wrote her very first line of code at the age of 89. Note the royal "we":

```
//MARK:- we are a good programmer
```

On the other hand, the return statement inside the guard statement will *return* from the closure, so nothing after that will be executed.